# How to show progress on rsync

Tags: linux, centos, webserver

Hi I'm using linux centos 7 64bit. I'm transferring files from one server to another using rsync. I want to display the progress ongoing like speed and time. How to display it?. I tried -p but it shows that's not a valid command.

Comment: -P, and learn how to use man pages or google

Answer (score 2):

use the --progress option see the man page for more info : https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync

Answer (score 0):

`-p` is not an option. `--progress` is a good default showing progress per file, `--info=progress2` gives you the progress overview for the entire Rsync operation. It shows bytes transferred, percentage of total run, current transfer speed, expected duration, file count transferred and progress on checking files. This is explained in greater detail in [this StackExchange comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/261139/389503). Once a file is completed, the stats for that file will still be printed.

For longer transfers of large files `-P` can be an option which implies `--partial --progress`. This leaves partial files in place at the destination in case a transfer is stopped. This makes it easier to resume an rsync operation at a later stage. Of course you can also combine this `--partial` flag with `--info=progress2` to get the live statistics for the entire run.